# how to count from 2 columns with different criteria in 1 column

Tags: xls

I hope that someone can help me get the correct formula for the following:

My data is as follows:

```
  C           G
 GRADE  |  COUNT/LB
 ------------------
 MINI   |    15
 MINI   |    20
 MINI   |    37
 MINI   |    39
 MINI   |    50
```

What I want is to count only the MINIs from column C that have a count of less than 36 and greater than 46, which in this case would be 3.

I have tried: `=countifs(c3:c7,"mini",g3:g7,"<36")+countifs(c3:c7,"mini",g3:g7,">46"` and I get a count of `0`; I have also tried, `=count(c3:c7,"mini")+sum(countif(g3:g7,{"<36,">46"}))` and get a total of `5`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please be sure to always use code blocks (see the formatting guide if you are unsure) to make your question more readable.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? I copied your code exactly (apart from adding a `)` at the end) and it worked, giving me 3. I am using Office 2011 on a Mac

Comment: THANKS @FRED, I WENT AHEAD AND TYPED THE 1ST FORMULA AGAIN AND IT WORKED!... I WONDER WHY IT STOPPED WORKING... WELL, IT'S WORKING NOW. THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: I'll make an answer then and can you accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `=countifs(c3:c7,"mini",g3:g7,"<36")+countifs(c3:c7,"mini",g3:g7,">46"` works out of the box for me, maybe you typed it wrong?